# How to make parent view handle tap and child view handle move in react-native?

Tags: react-native, gesture

I have one view inside the other. Yellow is parent, pink is child:

```tsx
<View
   style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
   onStartShouldSetResponder={() => {
     console.log('YELLOW START SHOULDSET');
     return true;
   }}
   onMoveShouldSetResponder={() => {
     console.log('YELLOW MOVE SHOULDSET');
     return false;
   }}
   onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() => {
     console.log('YELLOW CAPTURE');
     return false;
   }}
   onResponderTerminationRequest={() => {
     console.log('YELLOW TERMINATION REQUEST');
     return true;
   }}
   onResponderGrant={() => console.log('YELLOW GRANT')}
   onResponderReject={() => console.log('YELLOW REJECT')}
   onResponderTerminate={() => console.log('YELLOW TERMINATE')}
   onResponderRelease={() => console.log('YELLOW RELEASE')}
   onResponderEnd={() => console.log('YELLOW END')}
>
   <View
     style={{width: 80, height: 280, margin: 150, backgroundColor: 'pink'}}
     onStartShouldSetResponder={() => {
       console.log('PINK START SHOULDSET');
       return false;
     }}
     onMoveShouldSetResponder={() => {
       console.log('PINK MOVE SHOULSET');
       return true;
     }}
     onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture={() => {
       console.log('PINK MOVE SHOULSET CAPTURE');
       return true;
     }}
     onResponderTerminationRequest={() => {
       console.log('PINK TERMINATION REQUEST');
       return true;
     }}
     onResponderGrant={() => console.log('PINK GRANT')}
     onResponderReject={() => console.log('PINK REJECT')}
     onResponderEnd={() => console.log('PINK END')}
     onResponderTerminate={() => console.log('PINK TERMINATE')}
     onResponderRelease={() => console.log('PINK RELEASE')}
   />
</View>
```

I thought child could capture move (`onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture={() => true}`), but the child view is never asked to capture. Handling seems to be resolved only by the `onStartShouldSetResponder` returning value. But then, is there a way to handle only taps? How can I wait for more definition on the gesture to decide if a view will handle or ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() =>{}}` on the parent and make sure it returns false after your logic in the callback function. Like so, `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() =>{ // do all tasks here and after that // return false;  }}` in that case the parent will be responding to touches, while you do anything you want to do with the child.